# keyboard.is_pressed() breaking the loop

Tags: python, python-keyboard

I'm trying to do some python, the idea is that when a special key on the keyboard is pressed in this case $ and * it will make a web request to my server.

It works but only once, so if I type for example $ it will send the request, but if I type this again or * it doesn't work. So I think it's because it's breaking the loop because of the keyboard.is_pressed() and I don't know how to fix that

Here's the code:

```
import http.client
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('*'):
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('server_ip:server_port')
        payload = "{\n\t\"value\" : 0\n}"
        headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json",'Accept': "application/json"}
        conn.request("POST", "/api", payload, headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('$'):
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('server_ip:server_port')
        payload = "{\n\t\"value\" : 1\n}"
        headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json",'Accept': "application/json"}
        conn.request("POST", "/api", payload, headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
```

Comment: You could easily tell if the loop is being broken or not by using a debugger to step through your code. You really really should know how to do that from day 1 as a programmer of any kind.

Comment: Have any ideas to solve my issue ?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.  How do you know it's not working?  Do you actually have other code following this?

Comment: And, by the way, this is a tight 100% CPU loop.  You really need to add a `time.sleep(0.5)` in there to avoid chewing up an entire CPU.

Comment: Or use good old `input()`. Is there a reason not too? Is this part of a larger project - like a game? Make sure you have created a [mcve].

Comment: In this case, I can't use input()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there were two issues:

first, my server wasn't giving any responses, but the code wanted to get a response, so it was waiting a response. So I removed this code on the if and elif part

```
 res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
```

and secondly, I tried to create two **http.client.HTTPConnection()** with the same name, so it was giving me an error, so I changed the second to **conn2** and same for **headers2** and **payload2**

```
import http.client
import keyboard
import time

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('Page_Up'):
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('server_ip:server_port')
        headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json",'Accept': "application/json"}
        payload = "{\n\t\"value\" : 0\n}"
        conn.request("POST", "/api", payload, headers)
        time.sleep(0.5)

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('Page_Down'):
        conn2 = http.client.HTTPConnection('server_ip:server_port')
        headers2 = {'Content-Type': "application/json",'Accept': "application/json"}
        payload2 = "{\n\t\"value\" : 1\n}"
        conn2.request("POST", "/api", payload2, headers2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

How about adding 'continue' at the end of your if and elif?

like this:

```
import http.client
import keyboard
import time

keep_looping = True
while keep_looping:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('*'):
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('server_ip:server_port')
        payload = "{\n\t\"value\" : 0\n}"
        headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json",'Accept': "application/json"}
        conn.request("POST", "/api", payload, headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('$'):
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('server_ip:server_port')
        payload = "{\n\t\"value\" : 1\n}"
        headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json",'Accept': "application/json"}
        conn.request("POST", "/api", payload, headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('/'):  # Add this in so you can stop the loop when needed. Use any keypress you like.
        keep_looping = False
```

Comment: That is completely useless.  What do you think that would add?

Comment: I don't know why, but that's not working.